# |SOLVED| Get User Auth data from Firebase & add it to Firebase DB

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**Hello!**

**EDIT~**
*I've eventually managed to do this and wanted to share it just in case anyone else needs it. Most tutorials I've found were outdated and none of them seemed to work for me. But I've finally got everything to work so Here it is!*

---

**Sign Up -**
(I've created a sign up form with input fields for the username, extra info, password and email)

> *Make sure you import all firebase scripts you want to use and ABOVE all of them, the firebase app main script. In my case I only needed
>   Auth & Database - And BELOW all of this you put your Firebase App config and import either an
>   external .js file where you'll be using firebase functions or write it
>   all down there. This was a very silly mistake I did myself and I kept getting errors on the console. This is because I've been
>   trying to call my external .js file BEFORE importing the firebase main
>   scripts, which makes no sense right?*

So here's my **.js** file for the
sign up function:

```
//On a different .js file where I make use of most of my functions I've added this part 
//(just because I've defined more const for all my functions and I wanted to have them all 
//in one place):

//getting all elements -- I've only put in this example the ones that I've used for Sign Up
const signupBtn = document.getElementById("btnsignUp");

const txtEmail = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
const txtPassword = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
const userId = document.getElementById('txtName');
const discord = document.getElementById('txtDiscord');
const bday = document.getElementById('txtBday');
const gender = document.getElementById('txtGender');
const imgURL = document.getElementById('txtimgURL');

//getting references to the apps
const auth = firebase.auth();
const database = firebase.database();
const rootRef = database.ref('users');


//------------------------------------------------//


//firebase SIGN UP.js
signupBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){

    var email = txtEmail.value;
    var pass = txtPassword.value;

    //Signing up
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
    .then(() => {

      //send verification email
      sendVerificationEmail();
    }) 
    .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    //var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    alert("Error :" + errorMessage);
    });

  });
  //verification email function
  var sendVerificationEmail = () => {
    auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
    .then(() => {
      alert("Verification Email Sent! Check your mailbox.")
    })
    .catch(error => {
      alert("Error :" + errorMessage);
    })
  }      

  //DATABASE
  //'set' adds new data to he db
  signupBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    rootRef.child(userId.value).set({
        Email: txtEmail.value,
        Discord: discord.value,
        Gender: gender.value,
        Birthday: bday.value,
        ImgURL: imgURL.value,
        CC: 0,//Here I've added some more info that's be stored too along with 
        RS: 0,//the data that the user has provided
        Rupreets: 0,
        Bag: 1,//1: small, 2: medium, 3: big
    })    
  }); 
//And that's all!
```

---

**In my case, what I did with the database part is something like this:**

```
-App name-
|
+--Users:
 |
 +--username1
  |
  +-info1
  |
  +-info2
  |
  +-info2
 |
 +--username2
  |
  +-info1
  |
  +-info2
  |
  +-info2
```

---

*Well, I hope this will help somebody else too n.n*

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

A couple of things:

1. You never actually call `writeUserData` in your code snippet; you just define it.  If you don't call it, nothing will be written.
2. `userId` is never defined, so even if you called `writeUserData`, your database path would be be `undefined`.  You'd need to get the userId from `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`.  For more on that, see this Firebase doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users#get_a_users_profile  .

-- Edit --

Here's a code sample.  I haven't put in absolutely everything, just the relevant omissions:

```
//Signing up
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
    .then((data) => {

// createUserWithEmailAndPassWord returns a promise, which, when resolved will contain various user-related properties, so 
let id = data.User.uid;

      function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageURL) {
        firebase.database().ref('Users/' + userId).set({
          Username: name,
          Email: email,
          Profile_pic: imageURL,
        });
      }

// call your function, referencing the id above
writeUserData(id, name, email, imageURL)
```

If the idea of promises and calling functions isn't comfortable, you might look at a Javascript learning resource like [javascript.info](https://javascript.info)

Good luck!

Comment: Hi! And thank you n.n Would you mind showing me which parts of the code I should fix? I understand what you are telling me, but can't get how to fix it in my code. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi again! Thank you so much for your help, and the code, you are so kind! But sadly it doesn't seem to work either. I tried to copy what you did but i still have the same problem than before, the user is not even created when i check the firebase console. I even tried to define the writeUserData function, like i did for the email verification but still nothing.